# How to determine background app come to foreground in action of tapping local notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, region-monitoring

Apple doc [Getting the User’s Attention While in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) says

> Notifications are a way for an app that is suspended, is in the
>   background, or is not running to get the user’s attention.

My app is waked by iOS because of region monitoring and `is in the background` and post a local notification. User tap the notification and app will be in foreground.

How to determine app comes in foreground because of notification tapped by user?

Which delegate method will contains the notification information.

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOption or didReceiveLocalNotification
```

Comment: If app is suspended and not running then app will call "didFinishLaunchingWithOption" and if app is running in background then you will receive notification information in "didReceiveLocalNotification".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you your app running in background and you are tapped on LocalNotification Banner then you will get called following method:

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

after iOS 8:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
```

if app is not running in background you will get notification at:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
if ([launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey"]) {
 // here you will get
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can detect what's your App's status when UILocalNotification fired and if
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
is called, this makes sure that local notification is received.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        // Application was in the background when notification was delivered.
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can determine this by use of application.applicationState

```
 if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
     {
           NSLog(@" Inactive");
      // when you tapping on notification

     }
    else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground)
    {
           NSLog(@" background");
    }
    else
    {
          NSLog(@" Active");

    }
```